# Access violation when calling lambda in C++0x?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, lambda, c++11

I am receiving an access violation error when I call the callback:

```
typedef std::function<void(INT_PTR)> DIALOG_CALLBACK;
//Declaration
string userId=getUserId();
DIALOG_CALLBACK callTest=[userID, this] (INT_PTR) -> void{};//Does nothing yet
CustomDialog dlg=new CustomDialog("Are you sure you wish to run this operation", callTest);
....
//Definition
class CustomDialog: DialogBase{
public:
    DIALOG_CALLBACK callback;
    ....
}
//Call
void CustomDialog::OnOK(){
    callback(1);//Error occurs within call
}
```

The crash is occurring within the standard file `xxfunction`

```
_Ret operator()(_ARG0_A0) const
{   // call through stored object
    if (_Impl == 0)
        _Xfunc();
        return (_Impl->_Do_call(_A0_A1));//Crashes on this line
}
```

Links:

- [Lambda Functions](http://www.terrainformatica.com/2011/01/c0x-running-code-in-gui-thread-from-worker-threads/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that I deleted the this pointer at some point, which was what caused the problem.